# Python Help - Return DataFrame Value based on 2 conditions from 2 DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to modify a Python function to include an additional lookup value. I have 2 pandas dataframes (df_lookup and df1). The function below loops through df1['Name'] and compares to df_lookup['Name']. If the text from df_lookup['Name'] is found in df1['Name'] the df1['Category'] column is appended with the corresponding value from df_lookup['Category']. If there is not a match the text "Needs Category" is added to df1['Category'].

I'm trying to modify so that, in addition to the above, the df1['Account'] and df_lookup['Account'] must also match in order to update the df1['Category'] with the corresponding value from df_lookup['Category']

Current Function:

```
def func(x):
    global df_lookup
    for i in df_lookup['Name'].values:
        if i in x:
            return df_lookup.loc[df_lookup['Name'] == i, 'Category'].values[0]
    df_lookup = df_lookup.append({'Name': x, 'Category': 'Needs Category'}, ignore_index=True)
    return 'Needs Category'

df1['Category'] = df1['Name'].apply(lambda x: func(x))
```

Example of df1:

| Name | Amount | Account |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AMAZON.COM*ajlja09ja | 10 | 517200-00-240 |
| AMZN Mktp US *ajlkadf | 20 | 517200-00-240 |
| AMAZON.COM*ajlja09ja | 30 | 555555-00-000 |
| AMZN Mktp US *ajlkadf | 40 | 555555-00-111 |
| Shell Oil 4106981231 | 50 | 501150-00-100 |
| Shell Oil 4106778132 | 60 | 501150-00-200 |
| Newegg65484 | 70 | 517200-00-240 |
| Microsoft | 80 | 517200-00-240 |
| Valvoline | 90 | 501150-00-100 |
| Advanced Auto | 100 | 501150-00-100 |

Example of df_lookup:

| Name | Category | Account |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AMAZON | Amazon | 517200-00-240 |
| AMZN | Amazon | 517200-00-240 |
| SHELL OIL | Gas | 501150-00-100 |
| Newegg | Computer Parts | 517200-00-240 |
| Microsoft | Office 365 | 517200-00-240 |
| Valvoline | Oil Changes | 501150-00-100 |
| Advanced Auto | Car Maintenance | 501150-00-100 |

Desired Output:

- Pulls in the category when the ['Name'] and ['Accounts'] match and marks others with "Needs Category"
- The accounts on rows 3, 4, and 6 don't match and are marked with "Needs Category"

| Name | Amount | Account | Category |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AMAZON.COM*ajlja09ja | 10 | 517200-00-240 | Amazon |
| AMZN Mktp US *ajlkadf | 20 | 517200-00-240 | Amazon |
| AMAZON.COM*ajlja09ja | 30 | 555555-00-000 | Needs Category |
| AMZN Mktp US *ajlkadf | 40 | 555555-00-111 | Needs Category |
| Shell Oil 4106981231 | 50 | 501150-00-100 | Gas |
| Shell Oil 4106778132 | 60 | 501150-00-200 | Needs Category |
| Newegg65484 | 70 | 517200-00-240 | Computer Purchases |
| Microsoft | 80 | 517200-00-240 | Office 365 |
| Valvoline | 90 | 501150-00-100 | Oil Changes |
| Advanced Auto | 100 | 501150-00-100 | Car Maintenance |

I tried to modify with the code below but I receive a "TypeError: 'in ' requires string as left operand, not float" on the  if j in x: line.

Any suggestions or recommendations are greatly appreciated.

```
def func(x):
    global df_lookup
    for i, j in zip(df_lookup['Name'].values, df_lookup['Combined']):
        if i in x:
            if j in x:
                return df_lookup.loc[df_lookup['Name'] == i, 'Category'].values[0]
    df_lookup = df_lookup.append({'Name': x, 'Category': 'Needs Category'}, ignore_index=True)
    return 'Needs Category'

df['Category'] = df['Name'].apply(lambda x: func(x))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
x = df1.merge(df_lookup, on="Account", suffixes=("", "_y"), how="left")
x["Name_y"] = x.apply(
    lambda x: x["Name_y"] in x["Name"] if pd.notna(x["Name_y"]) else False,
    axis=1,
)
print(
    x.groupby(["Name", "Account"], as_index=False)
    .max()
    .drop(columns="Name_y")
    .sort_values("Account")
    .fillna("Needs Category")
    .reset_index(drop=True)
)
```

Prints:

```
                    Name        Account  Amount        Category
0   Shell Oil 4106981231  501150-00-100      50             Gas
1   Shell Oil 4106778132  501150-00-200      60  Needs Category
2   AMAZON.COM*ajlja09ja  517200-00-240      10          Amazon
3  AMZN Mktp US *ajlkadf  517200-00-240      20          Amazon
4   AMAZON.COM*ajlja09ja  555555-00-000      30  Needs Category
5  AMZN Mktp US *ajlkadf  555555-00-111      40  Needs Category
```

Comment: Thank you for you help. That works, however, I over simplified the data for the example. There can be multiple categories within one account. In the example data above I added Newegg and Microsoft to the 517200-00-240 account and valvoline and advanced auto to 501150-00-100. When there are multiple items within an account they do not merge properly.

Answer (score 0):

This is the work around I came up with.

The apply_name function applies the corresponding category from df_lookup to df based on the ['Name'] columns. This is a partial lookup - not an exact match. This presents a problem when the ['Name'] is used in two separate ['Account'] / ['Category'] combinations. (ie Amazon below - where the last row's category should be "Computer Purchases" but is showing up as "Amazon")

I added True / False helper columns for name_match, account_match to determine if the name and account in df matched df_lookup.

Then a final_match when True name_match and account_match are both True.

If final match is True the final_category is added from the ['Category'] column and others are blank.

Any thoughts or suggestions on how to modify to avoid the mismatched categories when the name is used between two accounts?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = [['Amazon', '10', '517200-00-240'],['AMZN Mktp', '20', '517200-00-240'], \
        ['Amazon.comaadfa', '30', '555555-00-000'],['AMZN Mktp', '40', '517200-00-245'], \
        ['Shell Oil 645564', '50', '501150-00-100'],['Shell Oil 564654','60', '501150-00-200'],\
        ['Newegg12323', '70', '517200-00-240'],['Microsofta923', '80', '517200-00-240'], \
        ['Valvoline', '90', '501150-00-100'],['Advanced Auto', '100', '501150-00-100'],\
        ['Amazon Prime - Technology','100','517200-00-240'] \
       ]
       
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name','Amount','Account'])

data2 = [['Amazon', 'Amazon', '517200-00-240'],['AMZN', 'Amazon', '517200-00-240'], \
         ['Shell Oil', 'Gas', '501150-00-100'], ['Newegg', 'Computer Purhcases', '517200-00-240'],\
         ['Microsoft', 'Office 365', '517200-00-240'], ['Valvoline', 'Oil Changes', '501150-00-100'], \
         ['Advanced Auto', 'Vechile Maintenance', '501150-00-100'],  \
         ['Amazon Prime - Technology', 'Computer Purhcases', '517200-00-240'],  \
        ]

df_lookup = pd.DataFrame(data2, columns = ['Name','Category','Account'])

# apply "Category" - if df['Name'] is in df_lookup['Name']
def apply_name(x):
    global df_lookup
    for i in df_lookup['Name'].values:
        if i in x:
            return df_lookup.loc[df_lookup['Name'] == i, 'Category'].values[0]
    df_lookup = df_lookup.append({'Name': x, 'Category': 'Needs Category'}, ignore_index=True)
    return 'Needs Category'

df['Category'] = df['Name'].apply(lambda x: apply_name(x))


# creates a name_match column (helper column)
def name_match(x):
    global df_lookup
    for i in df_lookup['Name'].values:
        if i in x:
            return df_lookup.loc[df_lookup['Name'] == i, 'Category'].values[0]
    df_lookup = df_lookup.append({'Name': x, 'Category': 'Needs Category'}, ignore_index=True)
    return 'Needs Category'


df['Name_Match'] = df['Name'].apply(lambda x: name_match(x))


# add a name helper column (True / False)
df['Name_Helper'] = np.where(df['Name_Match'] != '[]', True, False) 

# add an account match column (True / False)
df['Account_match'] = df['Account'].isin(df_lookup['Account'])

# add a final match column True if Name Helper and Account Match are both True - True values in this column should have
# a "final_category" listed
df['final_match'] = ((df['Name_Helper'] == True) & (df['Account_match'] == True))

# final category - applies the "Category" only to rows with True in the final_match column
df['final_category'] = np.where(df['final_match'] == True, df['Category'],'')

# formats dateframe to columns needed
final_df = df[['Name','Amount','Account','final_category']]
```